# How to create a smooth animation that eases toward the target

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

How can I create a smooth animation that eases in toward a target as it changes position?

[As this jsFiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/dannygarcia/LqP2R/), the animation stops or gets blocked during `moveTarget()` instead of continuing toward the new target coordinates.

What would be the ideal implementation / structure to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question here in case anyone else has this problem.

Instead of calculating `change` (`change = finish - begin`) each time `moveTarget()` fires, it is constantly being calculated in `onEnterFrame()`. So `moveTarget()` only responsible for getting the new X and Y positions.

This allows the values to ease toward the target.

I also permanently set the time value of the easing function to always be 1:

`easeIn(1, begin, change, duration);`

The example answer is in this revision jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dannygarcia/LqP2R/45/